# Should I use "We then" instead of "Then we"

Tags: grammar, word-order

In one academic paper I wrote "Then we ...", but the editor suggested me to change it into "We then ...". I would like to know if the former is really unnatural or both are acceptable.

Comment: It would depend on the context.  Could you provide the actual sentence and what comes BEFORE it.  This could be a formal vs. spoken issue.

Answer (score 2):

Both are fine, but when you begin a sentence with "then" as a *transition* from a previous clause, it *normally* has a comma after it:

> We listened for about an hour. Then, we left.

That isn't needed if you are not beginning a sentence:

> We listened for about an hour then we left.

If it is not indicating a succession of events and is instead being used to mean "therefore" then the comma is not necessary, for example:

> Waiter: "Are you intending to eat here?"
>   Customer: "No".
>   Waiter: "Then I must ask you to leave".

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Great grammatical explanation and examples from Astralbee above. My view is that 'We then ...' simply sounds more academic, and 'Then we ...' harks back to how we are taught to write simple sentences at primary school -- 'Then we went outside to play. Then we came inside for lunch.' The 'then' in 'We then' links more with the actions that you're about to explain, and so is more academic; the other way round, it links more to the WE phrase: We did this; we did that', and is about the people involved, rather than the subject of the sentence.